# Symfony2 generate invoice in PDF format

Tags: symfony, twig, pdf-generation

I need to generate invoice in PDF format and. I'm using symfony2 and twig as template engine. Is there any way to generate invoice without using any symfony2 bundle. Can you please show me simple example generate invoice with symfony2 and twig that has some CSS on it.

Thank you

Comment: I hate to say, but "without using any symfony2 bundle" kinda goes against the Symfony2 way :)

Comment: And why you use the Symfony2 framework, write your own ;-).

Comment: Can you please give me proper answer, and do not try to give me advices what shuloud I do. If you know annswer or you can give any alternative to my question please comment otherwise don't give stupid comments. Thank you

Comment: Question like this are off-topic on Stack Overflow. So, if you really want an help you need to read: [what topics can I ask on StackOverflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then update your answer with the properly content (well formatted) and wait...

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to generate pdf file without using SF2 bundles. But you can  generate it on the frontend if you have view as table. Here is demo: [Data Table (Table Tools)](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/)